# What is the Correct method to create Play Pause Button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button, countdown

I created a Countdown timer by following a tutorial, to start and stop countdown I have added a `FloatingActionButton` added play and pause icons using Ternary operator. right now, the button icon only changes from play to pause. when countdown is paused it does not change back to play icon.

here is my code:

```
FloatingActionButton(
                child: AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: controller,
                  builder: (context, child) {
                    return Icon(controller.isAnimating
                        ? Icons.pause
                        : Icons.play_arrow);
                  },
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (controller.isAnimating) {
                    controller.stop();
                  } else {
                    controller.reverse(
                        from:
                            controller.value == 0 ? 1.0 : controller.value);
                  }
                },
              )
```

[image]

I understand that I need to check if the Animation Controller is paused and change the play icon to pause icon but i dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try use setState after stop() and reverse()